# Is there a broadcast for when user starts and app in Android?

Tags: android, broadcast

I'm working on an application that requires to know when user opens other apps.After some research, I came down to this ActivityManager class and getRunningAppProcesses() method. But they only give me the full list of apps, and won't tell which one is currently open. Then I came down to using getRunningTask() or getRecentTasks() but according to this question, google has deprecated these two methods!
Is there a broadcast for what I'm looking for? I mean like the same way that we receive a broadcast that the screen turns on or things like those!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a broadcast for when user starts and app in Android?

No.